# How to get Zomato restaurant ID using restaurant link?

Tags: zomato-api

I want to get details of a restaurant in Zomato. I have it's link as the input (https://www.zomato.com/mumbai/fantasy-the-cake-shop-kalyan?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1). By browsing the documentation of Zomato APIs, I didn't found a way to get it.

I tried searching for the restaurant using search API but it returns many results.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to get the Restaurant ID programmatically or are you just tying to find the ID of the restaurant?

Comment: I need restaurant details using zomato link.... That's all

Comment: Would inspecting the source help you? You can look for the res_id.

Comment: Yeah, that's the option i considered... wanted an easier way though

Comment: Seems like the only way at this stage. They used to display the ID on the page where you could copy the URL but that no longer seems to exist.

Answer (score 3):

It's a two-step process:

1. Find out restaurant's city id, in your case, Mumbai's city id through the /cities API. It's a simple query search.
2. Use the city id from the above API call in the /search API, like, https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_type=city&entity_id=3&q=fantasy%20the%20cake%20shop%20kalyan

This would give all the basic information about a restaurant.

Answer (score 3):

View the page's source and search for window.RES_ID

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as you described. This Zomato's API approach is at least odd. It's almost immposible to GET any information about restaurant if you don't know res_id in advance and that's not possible to parse since Zomato will deny access.

This worked for me:

1. Obtain *user-key* from Zomato API Credentials (https://developers.zomato.com/api)
2. Search restaurant url via API (https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=84&entity_type=city&q=*RESTAURANT_URL*&category=7%2C9). The more specific you will be, the better results you'll get (This url is specified by city to *Prague (ID = 84)* and categories *Daily menus (ID = 7)* and *Lunch (ID = 9)*. If there is possibility do specify city, category or cuisine, it helps, but should't be necessary. Don't forget to define GET method in headers.
3. Loop or filter through json results and search for the wanted url. You might need to use method valueOf() to search for the same url. Be careful, you might need to add "*?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1*" at the end of your wanted url so it has the same format. Check that through Zomato API Documentation page.

```
for (i in body.restaurants) {
    var url_wanted = restaurant_url + '?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1'
    var url_in_json = body.restaurants[i].restaurant.url;
    if (url_wanted.valueOf() == url_in_json.valueOf()) {
        var restaurant_id = body.restaurants[i].restaurant.id;
    }
    console.log('Voala! We have res_id:' + restaurant_id);
}
```

4. There you have it. It could be easier though.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

once you have the url of the rseraunt's page you can simply look for a javascript object attribute named "window.RES_ID" and further use it in the api call.